# delete first X words and delimiters of a string - with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string such as `manipulate widgets add,1,2,3` (sorry, but I can't change the format).

I want to delete the first X words *and any delimiters which **preced** them*.

Let's take 3 as an example, thus deleting `manipulate widgets add` and leaving `,1,2,3`

Or, take `manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3` delete two words (`manipulate,widgets`) and leave `,add,1,2,3`

I can split the string into a list with `words = re.split('[' + delimiters + ']',inputString.strip())` but I can't simply delete the fist X words

with, say,

```
for i in range(1, numWorsdToRemove):
            del words[0]
```

and then `return ' '.join(words)` because that gives me `1 2 3 4`.

How can I do it and retain the original delimiters of the non-deleted words?

Just to make it interesting, the input string can contain multiple spaces or tabs between words; only one comma, but that might also have spaces pre/suc-ceeding it :

`manipulate  ,widgets     add ,  1, 2  ,    3`

Note that words are not guaranteed to be unique, so I can't take the index of the word after those to be deleted and use it to return a positional substring.

---

[Update] I accepted 'Kasramvd solution, but then found that it didn't correctly handle `remover('LET FOUR = 2 + 2', 2)` or `remover('A -1 B text.txt', 2)`, so now I am offering abounty.

---

[Update++]  delimiters are space, tab and comma. Everything else (including equals sign, minus sign, etc) is part of a word (although I would be happy if answerers would tell me how to add a new delimiter in future, should it become necessary)

Comment: What do you consider delimiters and what do you consider words?

Comment: delimiters are space and tab. Everything else is part of a word (although I would be happy if answerers would tell me how to add a new delimiter in future, should it become necessary)

Comment: You are still treating commas as delimiters in the 2nd case: `manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3` --> `,add,1,2,3`. The first and 2nd comma are treated as delimiters.

Comment: You are correct (+1). On reconsideration, commas _shouldd_ be treated as delimiters. Thanks for pointing that out; I have updated the questiom.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a RegEx like this

```
>>> import re
>>> regEx = re.compile(r'(\s*,?\s*)')
```

it means that, an optional comma followed or preceded by zero or more whitespace characters. The parenthesis is to create a matching group, which would retain the separators during the split.

Now split based on the RegEx and then skip the actual number of elements you don't want, along with the number of separators corresponding to those elements (for example, if you want to skip three elements, then there will be two separators between three elements. So you would want to remove the first five elements from the split data) and finally join them.

For example,

```
>>> def splitter(data, count):
...     return "".join(re.split(regEx, data)[count + (count - 1):])
... 
>>> splitter("manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3", 2)
',add,1,2,3'
>>> splitter("manipulate widgets add,1,2,3", 3)
',1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s1='manipulate widgets add,1,2,3'
# output desired ',1,2,3'
s2='manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3'
# delete two words (manipulate,widgets) and leave ,add,1,2,3
s3='manipulate  ,widgets     add ,  1, 2  ,    3'
# delete 2 or 3 words

import re

# for illustration 
print re.findall('\w+',s1)
print re.findall('\w+',s2)
print re.findall('\w+',s3)
print


def deletewords(s,n):
    a= re.findall('\w+',s)
    return ','.join(a[n:])

# examples for use    
print deletewords(s1,1)   
print deletewords(s2,2)    
print deletewords(s3,3)
```

output:

```
['manipulate', 'widgets', 'add', '1', '2', '3']
['manipulate', 'widgets', 'add', '1', '2', '3']
['manipulate', 'widgets', 'add', '1', '2', '3']

widgets,add,1,2,3
add,1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach:

```
from itertools import islice
import re

text = "manipulate widgets,.  add,1,2,3"

for x in islice(re.finditer(r'\b(\w+?)\b', text), 2, 3):
    print text[x.end():]
```

This will display:

```
,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `re.sub()`:

```
>>> def remover(s, n):
...     return re.sub(r'^(\s?\b\w+\b\s?){%s}'%n,'', s)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> remover(s,3)
',1,2,3'
>>> remover(s,2)
'add,1,2,3'
>>> remover(s,1)
'widgets add,1,2,3'
>>> remover(s,0)
'manipulate widgets add,1,2,3'
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the string `LET FOUR = 2 + 2` , when I ask it to delete the first 3 words :-(

Comment: Nor does if work when there is a negative number in the string `A B -1 C` (note thta the minus sign is not a spearator) when used at the place where want to cut E.G. `remove ('A -1 B text.txt', 2)`

Answer (score 1):

@original poster. Please edit the test cases, since some of your statements appear to be contradictory. Your second test case treats the comma as a separator.  But it also leaves the comma in the remainder, which is a 2nd issue. Either it is a separator or it isn't.

```
    # testcases  : string , #of words to remove, desired answer
s=['manipulate widgets add,1,2,3',
   'manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3',
   'manipulate  ,widgets     add ,  1, 2  ,    3',
   'manipulate  ,widgets     add ,  1, 2  ,    3',
   'LET X = 42',
   'LET FOUR = 2 + 2',
   'LET FOUR = 2 + 2',
   'A -1 B text.txt'']

X= [3,2,2,3,3,2,3,2]   

a= [',1,2,3',
    'add,1,2, 3',
    'add ,  1, 2  ,    3',
    ',  1, 2  ,    3',
    '42',
    '= 2 +2',
    '2 +2',
    'B text.txt']

#Just to make it interesting, the input string can contain multiple spaces or tabs between words;
#only one comma, but that might also have spaces pre/suc-ceeding it    
# <-- does that make the comma a word? 

# only delimiters are space and tab, not commas      
# <-- **does that make a single standing comma a word? **
# **2nd test case is contradictory to later statements, as comma is a delimiter here!**
```

Comment: My apologies. Comma is not a separator. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for your test cases:

```
>>> def remover(line, words):
...   parsed = re.split('(\s*,{0,1}\s*)', line, maxsplit=words)
...   return ''.join(parsed[-2:]).lstrip()
... 
>>> remover('LET FOUR = 2 + 2', 2)
'= 2 + 2'
>>> remover('A -1 B text.txt', 2)
'B text.txt'
>>> remover('manipulate widgets add,1,2,3', 3)
',1,2,3'
>>> remover('manipulate,widgets,add,1,2,3', 2)
',add,1,2,3'
>>> remover('manipulate  ,widgets     add ,  1, 2  ,    3', 2)
'add ,  1, 2  ,    3'
```

It wasn't clear what if anything to do with leading whitespace.  If it should be preserved, the `lstrip()` can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is very simple, and uses no regex:

```
def delete_leading_words(string, num_words, delimeters=' \t,'):
    if num_words == 0:
        return string

    i = 0
    while i < len(string) and string[i] in delimeters:
        i += 1
    while i < len(string) and string[i] not in delimeters:
        i += 1

    return delete_leading_words(string[i:], num_words-1, delimeters)
```

Comment: Thanks Mawg. However I realize that it was possible to attempt to delete too many words and get an out of bounds error. See edited code for fix (bounds check in while loop).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for certain what your definition of a "delimiter" and "word" are.  For example, in the `A -1 B text.txt` case, should the `-1` be treated as a word, or should the string be treated as if there are no words left to remove.  This is easily tailored with the regexp that Kasramvd provided.  For example, if you consider -1 a "word", then this basically does the trick:

```
import re


def remover(s, n):
    return re.sub(r'^(\s?\s*[^\s]+\s?){%s}' % n, '', s)

s = 'manipulate widgets add,1,2,3'

print('\nString is: {}\n'.format(s))
[print('Remove {}: '.format(x), remover(s, x)) for x in range(4)]

s = 'LET FOUR = 2 + 2 '

print('\nString is: {}\n', s)
[print('Remove {}: '.format(x), remover(s, x)) for x in range(7)]

s = 'A -1 B C text.txt'

print('\nString is: {}\n', s)
[print('Remove {}: '.format(x), remover(s, x)) for x in range(6)]
```

which produces:

```
String is: manipulate widgets add,1,2,3

Remove 0:  manipulate widgets add,1,2,3
Remove 1:  widgets add,1,2,3
Remove 2:  add,1,2,3
Remove 3:  

String is: {}
 LET FOUR = 2 + 2 
Remove 0:  LET FOUR = 2 + 2 
Remove 1:  FOUR = 2 + 2 
Remove 2:  = 2 + 2 
Remove 3:  2 + 2 
Remove 4:  + 2 
Remove 5:  2 
Remove 6:  

String is: {}
 A -1 B C text.txt
Remove 0:  A -1 B C text.txt
Remove 1:  -1 B C text.txt
Remove 2:  B C text.txt
Remove 3:  C text.txt
Remove 4:  text.txt
Remove 5:
```

But what about `=`?  Was `=` supposed to be a "word" or a "delimiter" or what?  If the rules are different, please let us know what the rules really are.

Comment: delimiters are space and tab. Everything else is part of a word (although I would be happy if answerers would tell me how to add a new delimiter in future, should it become necessary). `LET X = 42` is four words

Comment: I updated it to use whitespace as a delimiter.  If you have an additional delimiter just add it to the `[^\s]` part of the regular expression.  That is basically looking for characters that are not whitespace.